# Почему параметры функции не активны? Я их использую внутри функции но мне пишет что они не используются (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть функция handleForWorkInfoAboutClient в ней есть 2 параметра (key = '', value = ''), как видно они неактивыне в том плане что не подсвечиваются ярко красным, но в теле функции я их использую, так в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А что это за IDE?

Comment: Visual Studio Code, из-за того что они не подсвечены - они не используются там где я их внутри функции прописал :(

Comment: Вы путаете причину и следствие. Из-за того, что они не используются, они не подсвечены.